# shell: Using sed in backticks

Tags: shell, sed, escaping, backticks

I want to escape some special chars inside a string automatically.
I thought of echoing that string and pipe it through some seds. This doesn't seem to work inside of backticks. 
So why does

```
echo "foo[bar]" | sed 's/\[/\\[/g'
```

return

```
foo\[bar]
```

but

```
FOO=`echo "foo[bar]" | sed 's/\[/\\[/g'` && echo $FOO
```

just returns

```
foo[bar]
```

?

In contrast to sed, tr works perfectly inside of backticks:

```
FOO=`echo "foo[bar]" | tr '[' '-' ` && echo $FOO
```

returns

```
foo-bar]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes between the backticks.

```
FOO=`echo "foo[bar]" | sed 's/\\[/\\\\[/g'` && echo $FOO
```

Alternatively, use `$()` (this is actually the recommended method).

```
FOO=$(echo "foo[bar]" | sed 's/\[/\\[/g') && echo $FOO
```

Answer (score 16):

How about not using backticks but use $() ?

```
FOO=$(echo "foo[bar]" | sed 's/\[/\\[/g') && echo $FOO
```

if you insist on using backticks, I think you need to extra escape all \ into double \

```
FOO=`echo "foo[bar]" | sed 's/\\[/\\\\[/g'` && echo $FOO
```

Comment: +1 for `$()` Never, ever use backticks. There are so many advantaged to using `$()`. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: and +1 for the comment referring to Bash FAQ 82

Answer (score 2):

Usually, it's a case of underescaping

```
FOO=`echo "foo[bar]" | sed 's/\[/\\\[/g'` && echo $FOO
```